# How to test a new googleplay game

Tags: android, google-play

It's the first time I'm actually asking a question while i've found lots of answers here for about an year or so.

My question is that I'm almost done with my new app, including the icons and achievements,
but I can't test the app.

I've added my google account to the testers' account of the google developer console,
but my app doesn't seem to log me in.

So I'm asking if this is the right way to log a device onto the google play server.

//import

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
```

//logging in, with mGoogleApiClient a instance of the GoogleApiClient

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(Drive.API).addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE).build();
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

//unlocking an achievement, when the conditions are met

```
Games.Achievements.unlock(mGoogleApiClient,@strings/Achievement_ac1);
```

Eclipse doesn't show any errors but when I start the app, there's no sign of logging in

and it outputs an error and stops with the call of achivements.unlock

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a sign-in for the users?
The mGoogleApiClient only connects you to your App in the console. But you'll need to log in using a Google account too.

https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin

Comment: Well I put mGoogleApiClient.connect() like what you see at the second block...  wont that do?

Comment: Are you sure the connect() method is executed? And if so, do you have any methods in your class that will catch any errors that might occur?

Comment: No because the other lines execute just perfectly. Is there anything I have to do between making the instance and using .connect method?